# polynomial fitting in a semilogy plot in python

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I am trying to get a polynomial fit for my data. Currently, I am using polyfit from numpy to get the best fit in a loglog plot. But my goal is to get the data fit in a semilogy plot. My code looks as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.optimize as optimization

l = [ 0.006,   0.01,    0.014,   0.024,   0.0346,  0.049,   0.0535,  0.0736,  0.11  ]
f = [5.3375903383330048, 60.531976422513054, 89.111502526131474, 47.132498501584969, 17.447001214543118, 5.2583622688081455, 3.7779565652126865, 1.0621247249682186, 0.1922152085619766]


logx = np.log(l)
logy = np.log(f)
coeffs = np.polyfit(logx,logy,deg=3)
poly = np.poly1d(coeffs)
yfit = lambda x: np.exp(poly(np.log(x)))
plt.loglog(l,yfit(l), ':')




plt.loglog(l,f, 'o')
plt.show()
```

I would appreciate if you suggest what changes do I have to make to get a semilogy best fit curve. Also if there is any other package in python, please mention them too.[image]

Comment: When I look at a scatterplot of the raw data before taking logs, it looks to me as if the first data point is a possible strong outlier. Taking the log might be obscuring this, and it is worth a quick check to verify the values for this data point.

Comment: It is a raw observational data and looks exactly as expected in a semilogy plot. this loglog plot does  not reveal its true significane, that's why I need a semilogy fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this.

```
# log sacle    
x2 = np.linspace(np.min(l), np.max(l), 1000)
y2log = poly(np.log(x2))
plt.loglog(x2,np.exp(y2log), ':')

plt.loglog(l,f, 'o')
plt.show()
```